# PHP Check the checkbox if the data is same with database

Tags: php, database, checkbox

Can teach me the ways how to check the checkbox if the data already checked after i add the patient. For example, when i add patient, i checked 1 and 2. When i want to edit the patient info, the 1 and 2 checkbox must checked. Please help me solve the problem. Thank you.

```
//database.php
"CREATE TABLE tblmedicalhistory(Id varchar(12)NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, Bloodtype char(3), Diseases varchar(30))",
"CREATE TABLE tblmedicalrecord(Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , PRIMARY KEY (Id), MedicalRecordType varchar(20))",

//form1.php
<?php 
    $data = array();
    $DiseaseSplit = $medicalRec['Diseases'];
    $array = explode(", ",$DiseaseSplit);
    foreach ($array as $item) {
    $data[$item] = true;
}
?>
<tr>
<?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblmedicalrecord";
        $result = mysql_query ($query);
        echo "<label class='q' for='q1'></label>";
        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='q1[]'";
            echo "value=".$r['Id'].">".$r['MedicalRecordType']."</td>"; 
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
?>
</tr>
```

Comment: where you store records of the data already checked?

Comment: You need to add a column first from where you can determine the value is checked or NOT.

Comment: how the code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store first that from where you can determine the value is checked or NOT. Here I'm considering you have record of checked id for particular patient in array say :

```
$rec = array("1", "2");
```

means check-box 1 and check-box 2 are checked for that patient

```
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tblmedicalrecord";
        $result = mysql_query ($query);
        echo "<label class='q' for='q1'></label>";
        while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $str='';
            $str ="<tr>";
            $str .= "<td><input type='checkbox' name='q1[]'";
            $str .= "value=".$r['Id'].";
            if(in_array($r['Id'], $rec))
            {
                $str .= " checked ";
            }
            $str .= ">".$r['MedicalRecordType']."</td>"; 
            $str .= "</tr>";
            echo $str;
        }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>
```

Comment: $rec = array("1", "2"); how the pass the Diseases value from tblmedicalhistory to array? can teach me?

Answer (score 0):

When you click a button for editing the patient  (after the query that takes the values of the checkboxes from the database), you can pass the value of the checkboxes with javascript..

You're button

```
<button onclick="funzione<?php echo $i ?>();" id="editpatient"></button>
```

and the javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function funzione<?php echo $i ?>() 
    {
            <?php if($valueofcheckbox1): ?>
            $('#myCheck1').prop('checked', true).change();
            <?php elseif (!$valueofcheckbox1): ?>
            $('#myCheck1').prop('checked', false).change();
            <?php endif; ?>

           <?php if($valueofcheckbox2): ?>
            $('#myCheck2').prop('checked', true).change();
            <?php elseif (!$valueofcheckbox2): ?>
            $('#myCheck2').prop('checked', false).change();
            <?php endif; ?>
    }
</script>
```

where **myCheck1** and **myCheck2** are the checkboxes that you use to show if 1 and 2 are checked or not. and $valueofcheckbox2 / $valueofcheckbox1 are the variables that stores (from database) the value of the two checkboxes

I hope that this can help